# Provide pre-compiled library as install(TARGET ...) to other projects in CMake

Tags: cmake

I want to define a CMakeLists which is able to export a precompiled library to an out of source output folder.

This is how it currently look like:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.3)

project(duktape)

include_directories("./code" "./code")

file(GLOB allCodeFiles
    "./code/*.h"
    #"./code/*.cpp"
)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ./bin/duktape.dll)
set_property(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTY IMPORTED_IMPLIB ./lib/duktape.lib)

export(PACKAGE ${PROJECT_NAME})

Message(INSTALL_INCLUDE_DIR=${INSTALL_INCLUDE_DIR})

install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
  RUNTIME DESTINATION "${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}"
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION "${CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}"
  LIBRARY DESTINATION "${CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}"
  PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION "${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}/${PROJECT_NAME}/code"
  )
```

My current understanding of the install(TARGETS ...) is that it moves my libs to my out of soruce output folder and shares the headers to the project (some binary maybe) which depends on the lib.

The problem is that the export than tells:

```
CMake Error at C:/Test1/duktape-1.4.0.win32/CMakeLists.txt:30 (install):
install TARGETS given target "duktape" which does not exist in this directory.
```

**[Edit]:**
I still found no solution to just define a "project" to link a pre-compiled lib for integration purpose as a dependency to other projects?! I saw this kind of question ~10 times on google etc. and still can't belive that i didnt found one clear easy answer for this generic thing...

This is what i now end up with trying:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.3)

project(duktape)
#include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/DebugCmakeStuff.wtf)

# https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_library.html
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED IMPORTED GLOBAL)

set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ./include)
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES INTERFACE_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "")
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES INTERFACE_COMPILE_OPTIONS "")

set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/duktape.dll)
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/duktape.lib)
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION_DEBUG ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/duktape.dll)
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION_DEBUG ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/duktape.lib)
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/duktape.dll)
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/duktape.lib)

#target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} LINK_PUBLIC "duktape.lib")

#add_custom_target(${PROJECT_NAME}_Export MODULE)
#add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} duktape)

#export(PACKAGE ${PROJECT_NAME})

#install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
#  #EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME}_Targets
#  RUNTIME DESTINATION "${EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH}"
#  ARCHIVE DESTINATION "${LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH}"
#  LIBRARY DESTINATION "${LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH}"
#  PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION "${INSTALL_INCLUDE_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}/include")

#install(FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/duktape.dll DESTINATION "${EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH}")
#install(FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/duktape.lib DESTINATION "${LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH}")

#add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}
#                  PRE_LINK
#                  COMMAND copy ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/duktape.dll "${EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH}"
#                  COMMAND copy ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/duktape.lib "${LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH}"
#                  )

#add_custom_command(OUTPUT duktape.dll
#                   COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/duktape.dll ${EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH}/duktape.dll
#                  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/duktape.dll ${EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH}/duktape.dll
#                  COMMAND "copy ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/duktape.lib ${LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH}"
#                  )
```

So after 2 days wasting time with CMake and its crashes... i just realized that i'm most propably 90% fast, if i would have write the build files manually...

A solution would be nice

Answer (score 1):

Command flow `install(TARGETS)` installs only targets **built** within project. It doesn't install imported targets. See, e.g., [this bugreport](https://cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=14311).

For install imported libraries you may use `install(FILES)` command flow:

```
install(FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/duktape.dll
        DESTINATION <...>)
install(FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/duktape.lib
        DESTINATION <...>)
```

(In your code you install into `CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` and similar dirs, which refers to *build* tree. **Never install under build tree!**)

Comment: Ok, i miss used the CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY as i have set it to my intended output ... but thats a different story.

After changing the file to:
install(FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/duktape.dll DESTINATION "${EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH}")
install(FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/duktape.lib DESTINATION "${LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH}")

The duktape.lib is still not moved to the LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH
Is there something else needed, maybe on the project which it uses it?

Comment: Actions, speciafied in `install()` command, are executed on `make install`.